# Event subscription error from EVM compatible Substrate chain

Tags: evm, events, moonbeam, solidity, blockchain-events

i'm trying to listen events against a solidity smart contract deployed on EVM compatible Substrate chain and getting following error

> ```
> Error listening event ChangeOwner :  Error: Returned error: Method not found
> ```

Here's code script i'm using

```js
const RPC_URLS_WSS = {
    storagechain: process.env.STORAGECHAIN_WSS_RPC_URL,
    polygon: process.env.POLYGON_WSS_RPC_URL,
    ethereum: process.env.ETH_WSS_RPC_URL,
    temp: process.env.TEMP_CHAIN,
};

const getWSSWeb3Instance = (networkName) => {
    try {
        const web3 = new Web3(RPC_URLS_WSS[networkName]);
        return web3;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('getWSSWeb3Instance ~ err:', err);
    }
};

const chainEventListener = async (chainName) => {
    try {
        const web3 = getWSSWeb3Instance(chainName);
        web3.eth
            .subscribe(
                'logs',
                // {
                //   address: '0x3932970D99D3D4DD38C06986F0B09250B7588ED4',
                // },
                (err, event) = {
                    if(err) {
                        console.error('web3.eth.subscribe ~ err:', err);
                        return err;
                    }

                     console.log('Event', event);
                }
            )
            .on('connected', () => {
                console.log(`${chainName} is Connected.`);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('chainEventListener ~ err:', err);
    }
};
```

i wanted my chain to behave same as moonbeam is providing events subscription.
Here's [link](https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/build/eth-api/pubsub/#:%7E:text=used%20was%204.3.0.-,Subscribe%20to%20Event%20Logs,-Any%20contract%20that)